# How to not require specific version of an assembly

Tags: .net, version, .net-assembly

I have a project that I'm working on that references an assembly that references an assembly, like this:

```
Me
 |- A
 |  |- B v1.4.2
 |
 |- B v1.5
```

A doesn't need to reference `1.4.2` specifically, just anything greater than `1.4` or so. In the properties for `A`'s references, B says "Specific Version = False", but when I run `Me` with `B v1.5`, I get a `FileLoadException` looking for `B v1.4.2`. However, `B v1.5` is present, how to I make the CLR care less?

Comment: You need to add a [bindingRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) to point 1.4.* to 1.5.

Comment: [Redirecting Assembly Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx) contains all the background info needed

Comment: I saw that, but isn't there a different way to compile A such that it doesn't care what version of B it's given at runtime?

Comment: @kelloti Is the assembly Strong Name signed?

Comment: I need this to work in unit tests, so the bindingRedirect solution doesn't work

Comment: @kelloti i don't believe there is a way to do this without a binding redirect if `B` is signed. The CLR sees the version as being significant for a signed assembly and hence `B 1.5` and `B 1.4.2` are as different as C.dll and D.dll.

Comment: I think "specific version" just controls what reference in to the csproj file for compiling rather than the behaviour of the final dll, though not completely sure on that.

Answer (score 2):

Although binding redirects are the way to go here, sometimes that isn't possible - i.e. if you are plugin loading in another EXE. A practical solution we adopted was to hook the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event, listen for a failed binding to myassembly1.4.2.dll (for example) and explicitly return the assembly returned by a call to `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\assemblies\myassembly.1.5.0.dll")` instead. Binding redirect is better, but sometimes it's not practical.